# fetch 2d array in php

Tags: php, list, foreach, 2d

I have an array that looks like :

```
'Item1' => 
     array (size=5)
     0 => 'under Item1 1' 
     1 => 'under Item1 2' 
     2 => 'under Item1 3' 
     3 => 'under Item1 4'
'Item2' => 
    array (size=4)
    0 => 'under Item2 1' 
    1 => 'under Item2 2'
    2 => 'under Item2 3' 
    3 => 'under Item2 4'
```

And I want to fetch that array and show a menu : so the final result must be so :

```
        Item 1
             . under Item1 1
             . under Item1 2
             . under Item1 3
             . under Item1 4
        Item 2
             . under Item2 1
             . under Item2 2
             . under Item2 3
             . under Item2 4
```

Comment: You didn't mention which language you use.

Comment: php , it's mentioned in the title above ;)

Comment: Whoops my bad, I'm always looking the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array iteration:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($yourarray as $menu_name => $submenu) {
        echo '<li>'.$menu_name;
        echo '<ul>';

        foreach ($submenu as $submenu_name) {
            echo '<li>'.$submenu_name.'</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```